# Cast X to Y.getClass()

Tags: java, casting

I have many methods (3 for this example) that execute the same procedure. I would make a generic method for them to make it look clean but am having trouble with casting.

My 3 methods:

```
private void GetBeds(JSONObject deepSearchResults, Property p) {

        Object beds = Find_Key(deepSearchResults, "bedrooms");

        if (beds != null)
            p.beds = (Long) beds;
    }

    private void GetBaths(JSONObject deepSearchResults, Property p) {

        Object baths = Find_Key(deepSearchResults, "bathrooms");

        if (baths != null)
            p.baths = (double) baths;
    }

    private void GetRegion(JSONObject deepSearchResults, Property p) {

        Object region = Find_Key(deepSearchResults, "name");

        if (region != null)
            p.region = (String) region;
    }
```

I would like to call one method and clean up a lot of repetitive code. It would look something like:

```
 private void FillData(JSONObject deepSearchResults, Object o, String searchTerm) {

        Object response = Find_Key(deepSearchResults, searchTerm);

        if (response != null)
            o = (o.getClass()) response; //error "Not a statement"
    }
```

and I would call `FillData(...)` like:

```
 FillData(deepSearchResults,(Object)p.baths,"bathrooms");
```

But I don't think I'm using `getClass()` the right way. How would I programatically cast `response` to the type of `o` at runtime?

Comment: didn't read the full question, but try `o.getClass().cast(response)`

Comment: Boy, this whole idea just leaves me squirming with discomfort. Isn't one of the main reasons to use generics is to avoid this sort of casting, to avoid creating this sort of code that carries a great risk of throwing a ClassCastException?

Comment: In my case there's no risk of ClassCastException. I see where you're coming from.

Comment: If I remember my history correctly, Napoleon used words to that effect just before the battle of Waterloo

Comment: Even if it your cast works, you cannot change reference of an argument. "o = (o.getClass()) response" will be lost when you quit your function and p.baths will remain the same.
You can use a strategy pattern to achieve that.